# in VHDL, is it possible to create an array of std_logic_vector without using a type?

Tags: vhdl

In SystemVerilog I can create a multidimensional array as follows:

```
reg [31:0] mem[0:127];
```

However, in VHDL all of the examples for create a similar multidimensional arrays online in the VHDL book show that I must first create a type before creating the array. Example:

```
type   mem_t is array(0 to 127) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); 
signal mem :mem_t;
```

Is it possible to do this all in one step in VHDL like in verilog without first creating a type for the array?  Example:

```
signal mem :array(0 to 127) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
--syntax error:GHDL: Type mark expected in a subtype indication
--syntax error:vsim: near "array": (vcom-1576) expecting STRING or IDENTIFIER or << or '('
```

The reason why i'm asking is because i'm trying to avoid the use of a package to declare an array type, when connecting IO with an array that is connected  between to modules in VHDL.

Comment: Type mem_t is a single dimensional array type with a single index with an element type that is a single dimensional array type as well. It's not possible to slice a multidimensional array value. An index selects an element linearly while indices select an element geometrically.

Answer (score 8):

What you created is an array of an array - which is in general what you want.   What @Matthew Taylor created is a multidimensional array.

WIth VHDL-2008 the elements of a composite can be unconstrained, and hence, you can create:

```
type std_logic_aoa is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;
```

Realistic speaking this should be in a standard library - it is just not there currently.

And then you can use it by doing:

```
signal mem : std_logic_aoa (0 to 127)( 31 downto 0);
```

The reason you want an array of an array here is it allows you to do things like:

```
signal Data : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) ;
. . . 
Data <= mem(15) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

No. It isn't.

It is possible to create genuinely multi-dimensional arrays in VHDL, but you still need to create a new type. That is the VHDL way. So, you'll still need your package.

Here's a multi-dimensional *constrained* array:

```
type c_mem_t is array (0 to 127, 31 downto 0) of std_logic;
```

and here's a multi-dimensional *unconstrained* array:

```
type mem_t is array (natural range <>, natural range <>) of std_logic;
```

And you use them like this:

```
signal mem : c_mem_t;
signal mem : mem_t(0 to 127, 31 downto 0);
```

In VHDL-2002 either both dimensions must be constrained or both must be unconstrained. In VHDL-2008, you can have one constrained and one not:

```
type mem_t_2008 is array (natural range <>, 31 downto 0) of std_logic;
```

Comment: oh well...I guess SystemVerilog is better in category of creating anonymous arrays on the fly... and I just need to get used to using a package in vhdl...

Comment: VHDL is strongly typed, types are declared and each declaration in VHDL is unique. This requires a type declaration be made visible either directly or through selection.